# code for giving ratings

Tags: php, javascript, rating

I want to give some type of ratings to my posts in my site.

i want to do this coding some like the below site

http://www.comminit.com/en/node/222010/2754

i want to do this type of ratings in my site.

Does any one have code to do this.

or any one can tell from where i can download such type of codes...

Comment: What parts of it are you having difficulty with? If you'd like someone to build something for you, you could try rentacoder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing you own implementation, you can write to a file/db. Sorry, providing code will be a bit difficult.

How about using a provider to do it for you? A web search reveals: http://www.mywot.com/en/blog/adding-ratings-to-your-website